# Keep last 30 values and delete the rest

Tags: mysql

I have a table with user transactions with a timestamp. I now would like to keep the last 30 entries depending from the timestamp and delete all the rest entries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for an SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table retaining just the rows you want to keep. Then delete the old table. Then rename the new table

Comment: `DELETE FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 30, 18446744073709551615`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this just deleted 30 values, but I want to KEEP 30 values and just delete the rest

Comment: It worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about this way with **DELETE** and **SELECT** sub-query?

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 30) sort_timestamp
);
```

Intermediate subquery will help you to skip the error

> Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
>   'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: `Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: I also thought about a SELECT sub-query however didn't knew anything about DESC LIMIT 30 so far. However,  can you also post a version without depending on WHERE, as it doesn't work for me?

Comment: @Tester2389 I've edited my answer. Please have a look again I hope it will work for you now.